# Inspect Console Log in NodeJS Express

Tags: node.js, express

I am currently debugging a Nodejs Express application and I was wondering if there was a way to inspect the console log object similar to how you would do when developing web applications in Chrome or Firefox.
I.E:

```
  var myObj = [{"hello": "world"}];
  console.log(myObj);
```

Inspect Object:

[image]

Below is an example of a console.log() I am trying to inspect from Express:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [node-inspector](https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector) to debug your Node.js script in a browser.

[Here's](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=03qGA-GJXjI) a link to a video showing how to use the module.